# how to get the page source page of a page after log in

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code i am using

```
import requests
import sys
import urllib, urllib2, cookielib

USERNAME = ''
PASSWORD = ''

URL = 'https://apps1.coned.com/cemyaccount/MemberPages/MyAccounts.aspx?lang=eng'

def main():
    # Start a session so we can have persistant cookies
    session = requests.session()

    # This is the form data that the page sends when logging in
    login_data = {
        'ctl00$Main$Login1$UserName': USERNAME,
        'ctl00$Main$Login1$Password': PASSWORD,
        'submit': 'Sign In',
    }

    # Authenticate
    r = session.post(URL, data=login_data)

    # Trying to access a page that requires you to be logged in
    r = session.get("https://apps1.coned.com/cemyaccount/MemberPages/MyAccounts.aspx?lang=eng")
    print r.status_code
    print r.headers
    print r.content

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Hi

I am new to python and facing some issue.

I Need the source page of the page after log in, but the issue is the i am able to log in and get the code also, but when i see the source page, i am getting the page source code of the master page i.e. just the header and not the body.

Can some one help me in this ?

Comment: How did you understand that you were able to login? It looks like it redirected you to homepage again.

Comment: The response i got is 200, so assumed that i got logged in

Comment: and also the title of the page comes as the logged in page title.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `r.text`

`r.content` is for [binary content](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)

For different encoding:

`print(r.content.decode("ISO-8859-1"))` or

```
print(r.content.decode("cp1252"))
```

Or try to set the encoding to nothing so python will guess:

(before you do anything with `r.text` or `r.content`):

```
r.encoding = ""
```

Comment: c:\>C:\Python27\Python.exe C:\MiamiDade_Scraping\Request.py > c:\MiamiDade_Scrap
ing\txt.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\MiamiDade_Scraping\Request.py", line 32, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\MiamiDade_Scraping\Request.py", line 29, in main
    print r.text
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 279
84: ordinal not in range(128)------ This is the error which i get when i used r.text, thats the reason i used r.content

Comment: Looks like the encoding is wrong. What does 'r.encoding' say?

Comment: Looks like your page is encoded in something different than 'utf8' but is reporting 'utf8' maybe try with a different encoding.

Comment: i am again getting the same error --- c:\>C:\Python27\Python.exe C:\MiamiDade_Scraping\Request.py > c:\MiamiDade_Scrap ing\txt.txt Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\MiamiDade_Scraping\Request.py", line 32, in <module> main() File "C:\MiamiDade_Scraping\Request.py", line 29, in main print r.text UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 279 84: ordinal not in range(128)------ This is the error which i get when i used rint(r.content.decode("cp1252"))

Comment: i am still facing the same issue, same error when i used r.text after initializing r.encoding = ""

Comment: Try: `print(r.content.decode("ISO-8859-1", errors="ignore"))`

Comment: i am still getting the same issue.